# Safari is removing the hash from URL

Tags: url, hash, anchor

I have this problem and I've been looking other posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663410/safari-ignoring-removing-hashatags-when-clicking-hyperlinks/24778997#24778997), where they said that the link must have the slash (/) like: www.example.com/#item-1 in order to work fine on safari.

But I already have the slash and is still not working! the hash disappears when I click the link, so it's going to the url but on the top of it, not where anchor is placed.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem.  The URL was the correct format.  The issue, at least for me, was that my URL was old, and the web server's .htaccess file was re-directing the old URL to the correct URL.

Evidentially, iOS strips the window.location.hash value on certain types of server redirects.  Is this for security? Is it a bug?  I don't know.

My solution was to update the link to the correct URL and avoid the redirect by the server.

I hope this helps someone.