# Azure AD B2C reply URL fragment in Safari - AAD Reply URL issue

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

As per the below thread, Safari doesn't handle # in the reply URL and you need to a / to manage it (this isn't specific to AAD B2C)

[Safari ignoring/removing hashatags when clicking hyperlinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663410/safari-ignoring-removing-hashatags-when-clicking-hyperlinks)

Adding a / to the reply URL in AAD settings should fix this (eg: https://name.azurewebsites.net/oauth2/) but we see variable response where sometimes it works and other times it doesn't... has anyone got this working?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "sometimes it works and other times it doesn't"? Add error messages, screenshots, etc, as much info for people to be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, we used the Azure Documentation and got it working in the end. Thanks for coming back

Comment: Glad to hear, can you remove the question or add an answer and flag it as answered so that it doesn't sit unanswered here?