# Safari losing hash params on http redirection

Tags: safari, webkit, redirect, http-redirect

> I am facing an issue wherein the url fragments are not getting
>   preserved on redirect in Safari as they should be according to the
>   http specifications.

---

**Setting** -

```
`/url1` redirects to `/url2#hash`

`/url2` redirects to `/url3`
```

**Expected behaviour** -

```
Hitting `/url1` should redirect to `/url3#hash`
```

**Observed behaviour** -

```
Chrome/FF - Hitting `/url1` redirects to `/url3#hash`
Safari(11+) - Hitting `/url1` redirects to `/url3`
```

---

I did read the [issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24175) reported for earlier versions of Safari. I also tried the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663410/safari-ignoring-removing-hashatags-when-clicking-hyperlinks) posted in other SO threads in vain.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Same issue it's infuriating - did you find a fix?

Comment: Safari can at least reuse the fragment part if it is part of original URI. So, maybe you can think if it is possible for you to somehow introduce the "#" part in original request URL already: `/url1/#foo` -> `/url2` should make Safari to still open `/url2/#foo`.

Comment: I can't believe they haven't fixed this yet i hit this issue 4 years ago

Comment: @LT86 No fix yet.

Comment: @lef This is a chain of microservice calls redirecting from one place to another. Unfortunately/fortunately , anything that happens within is black box for the one hitting the first url

Comment: Seeing this issue too... 2 years after this post! 

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue today and made some additional observations. We were also able to reproduce the problem with an example Spring Boot app:

```java
@Controller
class RedirectController {

    @GetMapping("/url1")
    String url1() {
        return "redirect:/url2#hash";
    }

    @GetMapping("/url2")
    String url2() {
        return "redirect:/url3";
    }

    @GetMapping("/url3")
    @ResponseBody
    String url3() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

When running with Safari 14.1.2 on OSX 10.15.7 (Catalina) hitting `/url1/` leads to `/url3` without carrying over the fragment (#hash) from `/url2`.
But doing so with Safari 14.1.2 (same version) on OSX 11.5.2 (Big Sur) works. Hitting `/url1` leads to `/url3#hash`.

In any case hitting `/url1#this-is-fragment` leads to `/url3#this-is-fragment`.

*Our hypothesis is, that Safari (on Catalina) carries over fragments only if they are created in the browser and not on the server. Safari on Big Sur seems to behave like other browsers (e.g. Firefox and Chrome).*

Based on that hypothesis one "solution" is a client side redirect, for example via meta refresh:

```java
@Controller
class RedirectController {

    @GetMapping("/url1")
    @ResponseBody
    String url1ClientSideRedirect() {
        return """
            <html>
            <head>
              <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/url2#hash'">
            </head>
            <body></body>
            </html>
            """;
    }

    @GetMapping("/url2")
    String url2() {
        return "redirect:/url3";
    }

    @GetMapping("/url3")
    @ResponseBody
    String url3() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I suppose any client side JavaScript working with `window.location` would work as well.